# Grouping and Summarize SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

My table looks like the following:

| income | date | productid | invoiceid | customerid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 300 | 2015-01-01 | A | 1234551 | 1 |
| 300 | 2016-01-02 | A | 1234552 | 1 |
| 300 | 2016-01-03 | B | 1234553 | 2 |
| 300 | 2016-01-03 | A | 1234553 | 2 |
| 300 | 2016-01-04 | C | 1234554 | 3 |
| 300 | 2016-01-04 | C | 1234554 | 3 |
| 300 | 2016-01-08 | A | 1234556 | 3 |
| 300 | 2016-01-08 | B | 1234556 | 3 |
| 300 | 2016-01-11 | C | 1234557 | 3 |

I need to know : Number of invoices per customer, how many customers in total (for example one invoice = several customers, two invoices = two customers, three invoices = three customers, and so..).

What is the syntax for this query?

In my sample data above, customer 1 has two invoices, customer 2 one invoice and customer 3 three invoices. So there is one customer each with a count of 1, 2, and 3 invoices in my example.

Expected result:

| invoice_count | customers_with_this_invoice_count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |

I tried this syntax and I'm still stuck:

```
select * from
(
  select CustomerID,count(distinct InvoiceID) as 'Total Invoices'
  from exam
  GROUP BY CustomerID
) a
```

Comment: These are two steps. You should be able to write the query to count the number of invoices per customer. From there you can go on and write the query to get the number of customers per invoice counts. This is done by putting the first query as a subquery in the `FROM` clause or by using a `WITH` clause. Try something, and if you get stuck, come back and edit your request accordingly. Then we'll help you along.

Comment: By the way: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Paste your data as formatted text into your request instead. And then you can also put the result you expect from that data into your request.

Comment: You managed the first step, but you made no attempt for the second. It's the same thing: group and count. As people are quick on closing requests, but slow (at best) on re-opening them, here is the answer in a comment: `select invoice_count, count(*) as customers_with_this_invoice_count from (select customerid, count(distinct invoiceid) as invoice_count from exam group by customerid) counted group by invoice_count order by invoice_count;`

Comment: I've updated the request with proper formatting: Your sample data as formatted text, an explanation  how to get to the result figures, and the expected result matching the sample data. This is the effort you should put into your requests here on stackoverflow, and then they won't get closed anymore.

Comment: Single quotes are string literal delimiters by the way. If you use alias names that must be quoted (because of a blank for instance as in your case), you must use double quotes in standard SQL and brackets in SQL Server (`AS [Total Invoices]`). My suggestion: avoid names that must be quoted in the first place.

Comment: At last: Your database is not normalized. Your table allows the same invoice to have different invoice dates. That must not be the case. In a proper database, you'd make this two tables: an invoice table and a detail table (that you could call invoice_product or invoice_position or the like).

Answer (score 0):

Select Count(customerID),CustomerID From a
Group By customerID
Having Count(customerID) > 1

Comment: I need to see: two customers(1st column) received two invoices(2nd column) ...one customer received three invoices..